# Series expansion for integer arguments

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I need following

```
Series[Exp[-Sqrt[(a/p)]] HypergeometricU[n, m,b Sqrt[a/p]], {p,\[Infinity], 1}]
```

where `n` and `m` are any positive integers which do not have any relationship.

When I run this on Mathematica, it gives answer but only for non-integer `n` and `m` because it includes `Gamma[1 - m + n]` which has `ComplexInfinity` for negative `1 - m + n`.

How I can run above restricting answer to be positive integers `n` and `m`?

Comment: Did you try the Assumptions option for Series ?

Comment: @Lotus: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Mathematica 11.

```
Series[(Exp[-Sqrt[(a/p)]] HypergeometricU[n, m, b Sqrt[a/p]]) /. {m ->     2, n -> 3},
{p, \[Infinity], 1}]
```

> $$\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2 \sqrt{a} b}+\left(\log \left(\sqrt{a} b\right)-\frac{1}{2 b}+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{p}} \left(-\sqrt{a} \left(\log \left(\sqrt{a} b\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \left(3 \sqrt{a} b \log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)-4 \sqrt{a} b+6 \gamma  \sqrt{a} b+6 \sqrt{a} b \log \left(\sqrt{a} b\right)\right)+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{4 b}\right)+\frac{6 a b^3 \log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)-15 a b^3+12 \gamma  a b^3+12 a b^3 \log \left(\sqrt{a} b\right)-9 a b^2 \log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+12 a b^2-18 \gamma  a b^2-18 a b^2 \log \left(\sqrt{a} b\right)+3 a b \log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+3 a b+6 \gamma  a b+6 a b \log \left(\sqrt{a} b\right)-a}{12 b p}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{3/2}\right)  $$

Maple confirms it.

Comment: Can't we keep `m` and `n` as parameters? Not just specific values.

Comment: @Frey: As you wrote in your question, we can't use the output of Series[Exp[-Sqrt[(a/p)]] HypergeometricU[n, m,b Sqrt[a/p]], {p,\[Infinity], 1}]. Neither taking of limits nor assumptions  work.